# shell script to convert big endian to little endian

Tags: bash, endianness

how can I convert big endian to little endian.  I need to convert data from a file.

example data:

```
000000000000200200DC082DED2DEDED051F4032400454036A9891D53C370101EA0A
```

output:

```
0AEA0101373CD591986A0354044032401F05EDED2DED2D08DC000220000000000000
```

thanks
Ketan

found this script on the forum but it only does one at a time:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check 1st arg or stdin
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  exit
else
v=`cat /dev/stdin`
fi
else
v=$1
fi

i=${#v}

while [ $i -gt 0 ]
do
i=$[$i-2]
echo -n ${v:$i:2}
done
```

echo

Comment: Endianness usually refers to byte order within each word. In your example data, you seem to have a 272-bit word. Are you sure that's what you want? What architecture has such a word size?

Comment: Try: `sed 's/$/\o1/;:a;s/\(..\)\(.*\)\o1\(.*\)/\2\o1\1\3/;ta;s/^\o1//'` This will reverse ALL lines of a file, by **two** chars.

Comment: Try `(( i-=2 ))` instead of `i=$[$i-2]`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet both syntax will work, but `i=$[ $i -2 ]` (using square braces) is not recommended. I think the asker need to process a whole file: he said: *but it only does one at a time*.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I think when the OP said "it only does one at a time" they didn't mean one line at a time; they meant one pair of bytes at a time, while they want the whole byte array to be reversed. See their example input & desired output.

Comment: @k314159 The script work well! I've just tested them now: `bash ketan.sh <<<000000000000200200DC082DED2DEDED051F4032400454036A9891D53C370101EA0A`, this output: `0AEA0101373CD591986A0354044032401F05EDED2DED2D08DC000220000000000000`, then **quit**.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub `i=$[ $i -2 ]` is not recommended because it does not make any sense. When I write `X instead Y` I mean do **not** use `Y`, use `X`.

Comment: Voting to close this question. Based on the attempts to answer, and on the discussions on this issue, it seems that nobody knows for sure, **what** exactly is asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file containing hex digits and reverse it using bytes, where each byte is represented by two hex digits:

```
#/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
  tac -rs .. <<< "$line"
done
```

Save it as e.g. `rev.sh`, `chmod +x rev.sh`, and run: `rev.sh < myfile`

Comment: Linux only that...

Comment: @dawg It's not Linux only, but Bash only. The OP asked for a Shell script, which this is. Your answer requires installing Ruby on systems that don't have it.

Comment: `tac` is only on GNU utilities. Not on POSIX or BSD or MacOS unless manually installed. It looks like a solution! Just a Linux only solution...

Comment: @dawg point taken, it's a shell script, but specifically a Bash shell script, not a Posix shell script. Update: aargh I thought tac was a Bash built-in, which it's not!

Comment: But it is unrelated to Bash. The `tac` external utility is not necessarily everywhere that Bash is found.

Comment: And `rev` and `ruby` are not POSIX either. They just tend to be a *little* bit more common. Ed Morton's awk will run any where on any shell that is POSIX, so it is the broadest...

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{for (i=length($0)-1; i>0; i-=2) printf "%s", substr($0,i,2); print ""}' file
0AEA0101373CD591986A0354044032401F05EDED2DED2D08DC000220000000000000
```

or using GNU awk for `FPAT`:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='..' '{for (i=NF; i>=1; i--) printf "%s", $i; print ""}' file
0AEA0101373CD591986A0354044032401F05EDED2DED2D08DC000220000000000000
```

Alternatively, using `rev` to reverse the whole line and any `sed` to swap the characters in every pair:

```
$ rev file | sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g'
0AEA0101373CD591986A0354044032401F05EDED2DED2D08DC000220000000000000
```

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g' file | rev
0AEA0101373CD591986A0354044032401F05EDED2DED2D08DC000220000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is:

1. Reverse the string;
2. Rereverse each pair of two hex digits.

If so:

```
s='000000000000200200DC082DED2DEDED051F4032400454036A9891D53C370101EA0A'

ruby -lne 'puts $_.reverse.scan(/../).map(&:reverse).join' <<< "$s"
```

Or with `rev` and `sed`:

```
echo "$s" | rev | sed -E 's/(.)(.)/\2\1/g'
```

Either prints:

```
0AEA0101373CD591986A0354044032401F05EDED2DED2D08DC000220000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nlE 'say reverse unpack "(A2)*"' file
```

- for each line of `file`:

  - split into array of two-character strings
  - reverse the array
  - print it

May not produce desired output if line contains an odd number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

From *man dd*:

> swab     Swap every pair of input bytes.
> If an input buffer has an
> odd number of  bytes, the last byte will be ignored during swapping.

Therefore,

```
dd conv=swab example_data_file output_data_file
```

should do the job.

Comment: this doesn't convert the sample input into the sample output

Comment: @jhnc : You have a point here. I was just focusing on the question "converting big endian to little endian".  But, assuming that the sample data posted, is the hex representation of the input, then the posted output is simply a `rev` of the input. What do I miss here?

Comment: q isn't clear on whether there are multiple lines. but if so you would need to `dd` each one separately. consider: `printf 'oeoe\noeoe\n' | dd conv=swab`

Comment: @jhnc : Hmmm, your printf would produce hexadecimal _6F65 6F65 0A6F 656F 650A_ and the _swab_  would turn this into _656F 656F 6F0A 6F65 0A65_, and this indeed is endian of the byte stream swapped, isn't it? From my understanding, big/little endian refers to the order of the two bytes in a sequence of  16 bit words.

Comment: yes, it's very open to interpretation of what the question is asking for. Most answers have assumed processing of independent lines of data (so expected output of `eoeo\neoeo\n`)