Binary integer representation printing in Linux / Shell
I have a Python scripts for printing a decimal string-represented integer as a 4-bytes little-endian representation:
import sys
i4 = int(sys.argv[1])
sys.stdout.buffer.write(i4.to_bytes(4, 'little'))
# import struct; sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('<I', i4))

Is there a nice way to do it in with pure Linux / shell commands? (e.g. printf / awk / sed)
Thanks!

Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77680291/2422776

What's in argv[1] and what's the expected output?

shell is not really suited to manipulating binary data.

You can use printf to convert decimal to fixed-width hexadecimal.  The result will be in standard most-significant to least-significant digit order:
printf '%08x' "$1"

If you want little-endian byte order then you need to capture that result and reorder the bytes, or else separate and re-order the bytes first, then convert to hex.
For example, with Bash and the GNU version of cut, you might do this:
bytes=($(printf '%08x' "$1" | cut -b1-2,3-4,5-6,7-8 --output-delimiter ' '))
echo "${bytes[3]}${bytes[2]}${bytes[1]}${bytes[0]}"

That does the hex conversion all in one piece, then splits the hex digit pairs from each other and gathers them into an array, which is finally (manually) output in reverse order.
Alternatively, the split-first approach might look like this:
num=$1
for i in {1..4}; do
  printf '%02x' $((num % 256))
  num=$((num / 256))
done
echo

That picks off the bytes one by one, least-significant first, and separately converts each to hexadecimal.
Addendum - raw binary data
However you produce the hexadecimal, you can convert to raw binary data by passing it through xxd -r -p.  For example,
bytes=($(printf '%08x' "$1" | cut -b1-2,3-4,5-6,7-8 --output-delimiter ' '))
xxd -r -p <<<"${bytes[3]}${bytes[2]}${bytes[1]}${bytes[0]}"


Maybe I'm  misunderstanding your answer, but I don't need a hexadecimal/ASCII representation, I need actual raw bytes containing the integer, as it is in two's complement format e.g. in C for int32_t, i.e. have exactly 4 bytes on the output...

Raw bytes represented how, @VadimKantorov? This provides a hexadecimal representation of the raw bytes.  You cannot store bytes with value 0 in a shell variable, and it's at best tricky to print them.  But I'll see what I can do.

My Python snippets achieve this purpose. I wonder if I can do it with more basic shell tools than Python... So how to output raw bytes (not hex) is precisely the question...

@VadimKantorov, you can achieve this by passing the hexadecimal through xxd -r -p.  I have added that to this answer.

Something like this (bash only) perhaps may help you
#! /bin/bash

n="$1"
r='(..)(..)(..)(..)'
h=$(printf '%08x\n' "$n")
if [[ "$h" =~ $r ]]; then
    printf '%b%b%b%b' "\\x${BASH_REMATCH[4]}" "\\x${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" "\\x${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "\\x${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi


So here are 2 POSIX-compliant and fully portable awk functions, one for hex representation, the other for combined BE32 and LE32 actual binary bytes. Specify either L or LE (in any case) in 2nd function argument to request for LE32, otherwise it defaults to BE32.
It also has auto detection for byte mode vs. UTF-8 mode, and adjusts necessary offsets accordingly. hex32() assumes unsigned input only, but binary32() properly range clamps, including negative inputs.
function hex32(__, _, ___) {

    return (__ = int(__)) < (___ = (_ += _ += _ ^= _<_)^(_ * _)) \
        ? sprintf("0x[%.*X]", _ + _, __) \
        : sprintf("0x[%.*X][%.*X]", _ += _, 
                            (__ - (__ %= ___)) / ___, _, __)
}
function binary32(__, _, _1_, _2_, _3_, _4_) {

             _1_ = int(__)
          __ = _ = (_ ~ /^[Ll][Ee]?$/)
      _ ^=   _4_ =  _ += _ += _ += !_
    _1_ += ((_1_ %= _4_ = _^_4_) < !_) * _4_

    _4_ = ((_3_ = ((_2_ = (_1_ - (_1_ %= _)) / _) \
            - (_2_ %= _)) / _) - (_3_ %= _)) / _

    return sprintf("%.*s%c%c%c%c", (__ && (_3_ += _2_ - (_2_ = _3_)) < \
                                          (_4_ += _1_ - (_1_ = _4_))) < !_,
                                   FLG_AWK_UTF8 ? _ *= _ * _ : _ = !_,
                                   _4_ + _, _3_ + _, _2_ + _, _1_ + _)
}
BEGIN { FLG_AWK_UTF8 = !+sprintf("%c", 5^5) }


        89 0x[00000059]
      4567 0x[000011D7]
     76543 0x[00012AFF]

  23456789 0x[0165EC15]
  61277761 0x[03A70641]

3221225473 0x[C0000001]
3745221223 0x[DF3B8A67]



FLG_AWK_UTF8 = !+sprintf("%c", 5^5)

The detection here works by leveraging 8-bit wraparound behavior in byte mode to yield the ASCII integer "5" for an input value of 5^5, but that same value in Unicode mode prints this 3-byte UTF-8 Telugu character "వ" instead.
